# Spring Security: Custom LdapAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to use a custom LdapAuthenticationProvider, with only one minor change, in order to execute the authentication, a certain precondition needs to be met.

What I want basically:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!precondition) {
        throw new DisabledException("");
    }

    return super.authenticate(authentication);
}
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder);

    if (ldapSecurityConfig.isLdapEnabled()) {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(ldapContextSource)
                .userSearchFilter(ldapSecurityConfig.getUserSearchFilter())
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the line

```
auth.ldapAuthentication()
```

creates an LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer object, and its build method instantiates an  LdapAuthenticationProvider object:

```
LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator, authoritiesPopulator);
```

It looks like I don't have control over which LdapAuthenticationProvider will be used at the end.

As a workaround, I could check the precondition in my UserDetailsContextMapper object and throw an exception if it is not met, but it is not optimal, since in this case the LDAP server will be queried even if it's not needed.

My question is, how can I force that my custom provider will be used, or is there any other "simple" way to achieve the behaviour I want?

Comment: Have you found a solution?